# How to Activate and deactivate the RTL features in AI and PS CC 2014

Tags: adobe-illustrator

how to get access to all Arabic / Hebrew language features in the last updated Adobe products 2014.1 specially Illustrator.

Comment: no sir it is completely different, I think writing in RTL in the new updates made by Adobe is completely different from the answer already posted in the link you provided. the best answer is from June 2012 !!

Comment: ah, forgive me then. I just thought I'd seen this questions before, but had no clue it was *that* outdated.

Comment: never mind, actually I have RTL on my Illustrator 2014.1 but the same version used by my colleagues do not have. actually I have a completely diffrent preferences dialogue box in Illustrator. and nothing online can help. so how could it activated on my machine in the first place?

Comment: by the way, my illustrator have the Right-to-Left type tool icon activated. which is the typing tool having a right to left arrow underneath. while all my colleagues didn't have this icon.